# How to enable device administration in eclipse?

Tags: android, permissions, admin

Alright. I first wanna apologize for creating another question as I did come across a few things on Google but i am just not fully understanding the things I've found. The three links i found are [Make your application a device administrator](http://rootfs.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/android-make-your-application-a-device-administrator/) and [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html%22) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html)

I completely understand the whole XML part but the part I'm not grasping is where do i put the code i want to run? Like i am trying to place the device into standby mode after executing some code. I know i need to use PowerManager but in order to do this i need to make my app an administrator. Also in the first link i'm not sure what this means `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE);` and why the `REQUEST_ENABLE` is underlined in red giving **Cannot be resolved to a variable** error and in the tutorial there was nothing mentioned about creating `REQUEST_ENABLE` variable or method or class or anything.

Thanks everyone in advanced for helping me wrap my head around this!

Comment: That error will be resolved by using "private final int REQUEST_ENABLE = 1;" in section of global variable declaration. And put that code exactly where you want your device admin to be activated

Comment: Okay i added that and got rid of the error. Now i didnt add any of my code as i am trying to figure this out.. 

But when i run the code i have this set to run when you tick a check box. But nothing happens, it doesnt prompt user for access. What did i miss?

 if(!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)){
         Intent intent = new     Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
             intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "We need to turn off the device");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE);

Comment: Scratch that last comment -.- lol. It works but i had to manually enable it inside the security section of the device. I need to figure out how to automatically bring up that setting when my activity starts. (I am pretty sure i can find that on google)

Comment: Alright i have one last question. What is this for? I commented it out of my app and it still worked so i am not sure what its for or why i need it.<br/> <--- why doesnt that work?

Comment: `if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
// try to become active – must happen here in this activity, to get result
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
mAdminName);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
“Additional text explaining why this needs to be added.”);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE);
} else {
// Already is a device administrator, can do security operations now.
mDPM.lockNow();
}`